# Basic set notation in combining different ranges of numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What is the proper way to specify a set which contains all even numbers between 1 and 10, and all odd numbers between 11 and 30?

Would this work?

$$ U = \{n, m\ |\ n \ \text{is even},\ 1 \le n \le 10, m\ \text{is odd}, 11 \le m \le 30\} $$

Comment: I would say yes, though it might be a bit confusing to have both $n$ and $m$.  You could use instead $\{n\mid (n~\text{is even and}~1\leq n\leq 10)~\text{or}~(n~\text{is odd and}~11\leq n\leq 30)\}$.  Alternatively, one could express the set using intersections and unions of known sets.  E.g. $(2\Bbb N\cap [1,10])\cup ((2\Bbb N+1)\cap [11,30])$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't denote the elements of your set as $n,m$. What is an $n,m$? Is it a pair? You can separate the set as a union of two subsets:
$$\{n| n=2k, k\in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } 1\leq n\leq 10 \}\cup\{m|m=2k-1, k\in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } 11\leq m \leq 30\}$$